# what is the maximum number of push notification that can be sent through mspn in windows phone in a day?

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns, app-hub

can someone tell me what is the maximum number of push notification that can be sent through mspn in windows phone in a day. Or is it unlimited? If there is any limit, please answer following questions as well

- Maximum number of notification that can be sent to mspn from cloud service per day
- Maximum number of notification that can be sent to a single device per day
- Additional cost per notification after the limit is reached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402558(v=vs.92).aspx.

> We recommend setting up an authenticated web service to send your notifications to the Microsoft Push Notification Service, because communication occurs over an HTTPS interface for better security. Authenticated web services do not have a daily limit on the number of push notifications they can send. Unauthenticated web services, on the other hand, are throttled at a rate of 500 push notifications per subscription per day

Comment: I tried to send 250 pns to a device. It gave me 406(Not acceptable) errors continuously. However, when I tried to stop the service and start again, it worked beautifully. Is there any limit on number of PNs that can be sent per sec?